# FastTextKeyedVectors difference between vectors, vectors_vocab and vectors_ngrams instance variables

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I downloaded [wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.bin.zip](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.bin.zip) and loaded it as follows:

```py
import gensim
print(gensim.__version__)
model = gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model('./wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.bin')
print(type(model))
model_keyedvectors = model.wv
print(type(model_keyedvectors))
model_keyedvectors.save('./wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors')
```

As expected, I see the following output:

```sh
3.8.1
<class 'gensim.models.fasttext.FastText'>
<class 'gensim.models.keyedvectors.FastTextKeyedVectors'>
```

I also see the following three numpy arrays serialized to the disk:

```sh
$ du -h wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors*
127M    wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors
2.3G    wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors.vectors_ngrams.npy
2.3G    wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors.vectors.npy
2.3G    wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.keyedvectors.vectors_vocab.npy
```

I understand `vectors_vocab.npy` and `vectors_ngrams.npy`, however, what is `vectors.npy` is used for internally in `gensim.models.keyedvectors.FastTextKeyedVectors`? If I look at the source code for finding out [word vector](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/3.8.1/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L2090), I do not see how attribute `vectors` is being used anywhere. I see the attributes `vectors_vocab` and `vectors_ngrams` bing used. However, if I remove `vectors.npy` file, I am not able to load the model using `gensim.models.keyedvectors.FastTextKeyedVectors.load` method.

Can someone please explain where this variable is used? Can I remove it if all I am interested is in looking word vectors (to reduce memory footprint)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`vectors_ngrams` are the buckets storing the vectors that are learned from word-fragments (character-n-grams). It's a fixed size no matter how many n-grams are encountered - as multiple n-grams can 'collide' into the same slot.

`vectors_vocab` are the *full-word-token* vectors as trained by the FastText algorithm, for full-words of interest. However, note that the actual word-vector, as returned by FastText for an in-vocabulary word, is defined as being this vector **plus** all the subword vectors.

`vectors` stores the actual, returnable full-word vectors for in-vocabulary words. That is: it's the precalculated combination of the `vectors_vocab` value plus all the word's n-gram vectors.

So, `vectors` is never directly trained, and can always be recalculated from the other arrays. It probably *should not* be stored as part of the saved model (as it's redundant info that could be reconstructed on demand).

(It could possibly even be made an optional optimization, for the specific case of FastText – with users who are willing to save memory, but have slower per-word lookup, discarding it. However, this would complicate the very common and important `most_similar()`-like operations, which are far more efficient if they have a full, ready array of all potential-answer word-vectors.)

If you don't see `vectors` being directly accessed, perhaps you're not considering methods inherited from superclasses.

While any model that was saved with `vectors` present will need that file when later `.load()`ed, you could conceivably save on disk-storage by discarding the `model.wv.vectors` property *before* saving, then forcing its reconstruction after loading. You would still be paying the RAM cost, when the model is loaded.

After `vectors` is calculated, and if you're completely done training, you could conceivably discard the `vectors_vocab` property to save RAM. (For any known word, the `vectors` can be consulted directly for instant look-up, and `vectors_vocab` is only needed in the case of further training or needing to re-generate `vectors`.)